# How can I get the current action in Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a plugin in my Zend Framework application that checks login status after every request, and reroutes the user to the login action if their session is invalid or expired.  I would like to cache the previous request action so that, after a successful login attempt, I can redirect them back to their previous request.

I have found the documentation on the setActionController() method, but I can't find anything on a "getActionController()" method.  Does one exist?  If so, does anyone have any information they could link me to on it?  If not, what's the best way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

In the default routing, both the controller and the action are always passed along with the request.

```
$controller = $this->getRequest()->getControllerName();
$action = $this->getRequest()->getActionName();
```

Comment: Dang, I think I even knew that somewhere in the back of my lizard brain.  Thanks!

Answer (score 37):

If you are not in controller, use:

```
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getControllerName();
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getActionName();
```